I am not able to use remote desktop. It was working fine as soon as I connected PC through SSH from my local machine using VSCode
I am not able to use remote desktop. It was working fine as soon as I connected PC through SSH from my local machine using VSCode.
kshz@Monaco:~$ sudo systemctl status gnome-remote-desktop
× gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gnome-remote-desktop.service; enab>
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2024-09-17 17:35:37 IST; 16min a>
   Main PID: 9618 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
        CPU: 15ms

Sep 17 17:35:37 Monaco systemd[1]: gnome-remote-desktop.service: Scheduled rest>
Sep 17 17:35:37 Monaco systemd[1]: gnome-remote-desktop.service: Start request >
Sep 17 17:35:37 Monaco systemd[1]: gnome-remote-desktop.service: Failed with re>
Sep 17 17:35:37 Monaco systemd[1]: Failed to start gnome-remote-desktop.service>
lines 1-10/10 (END)


what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
